# Using PHP and SQL to insert data from HTML form and other tables into new table

Tags: php, sql

sealife_customer:

[image: customer table]

sealife_trip

[image: trip information table]

My query for inserting data from the HTML form (trip_id, email, pay_num, pay_expiry, pay_cvv) and getting data from the sealife_customer and sealife_trip table:

```
$Query = "insert into sealife_booking values ('$trip_id', '$email', depart_date, first_name, last_name, address, phone, '$pay_num', '$pay_expiry', '$pay_cvv'')
        SELECT t1.email, t2.depart_date, t1.first_name, t1.last_name, t1.address, t1.phone
        FROM sealife_customer t1
        LEFT JOIN sealife_trip t2
        WHERE t1.email = '$email'";
```

So I'm unsure how I combine both the HTML form variables, and the already established data in the customer and trip tables to insert into the new table sealife_booking. The email is the key that links the customer to the booking.

How can I combine both tables and HTML form data to insert in the new table?

Thank you.

Comment: There is so much wrong in your query.

Comment: The number of columns in your insert statement doesn't match the select statement. You are inserting literal values (quoted strings), not variables. Perhaps there is some reading on php and sql you should read?